# Rails routes and helper functions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have defined the following route on my routes file:

```
match "/users/:id/courses", :to => 'users#courses'
```

Do you know what is the helper function that is generated for that route?

I have tried this:

```
users_courses_path(current_user)
user_courses_path(current_user)
users_course_path(current_user)
user_course_path(current_user)
```

But none of those works

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better than that, you can create your own helper, for example:

```
match "/users/:id/courses", :to => 'users#courses', :as => :users_courses # or anything you want
```